# Generate Password through Javascript and render in back to HTML

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to build a simple password generator via JavaScript and the function just won't return anything, it will return nothing(blank).

```js
let chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let randomPass = ""
let passLen = 16


function ranNum() {
    for ( let i=0; i<passLen.length; i++){
        let randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length) + 1
        randomPass += chars.charAt(randomLetter)
        
    }
    return randomPass
}

function genPass() {
    document.getElementById("div1").textContent = ranNum()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="genPass()">Generate</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: `passLen` is a number, which doesn't have a `.length` property. Did you mean `for ( let i=0; i<passLen; i++)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is not executing because you are asking for passLen.length, and passLen is an integer it wont have a length, and then the loop won't run. just change your line
`for ( let i=0; i<passLen.length; i++){` to `for ( let i=0; i<passLen; i++){` and it will run fine.

```js
let chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let randomPass = ""
let passLen = 16


function ranNum() {
console.log('generate');
    for ( let i=0; i<passLen; i++){
        let randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length) + 1
        randomPass += chars.charAt(randomLetter);
        console.log(randomLetter);
        
    }
    return randomPass
}

function genPass() {
    document.getElementById("div1").textContent = ranNum()
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">test</div>

<button onclick="genPass()">Generate password</button>
```

Comment: @Zach Jensz, so close. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a mistake from my side

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, passLen is not an array, it's already a length. So you don't need `passLen.length` only `passLen`.

```js
let chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let randomPass = ""
let passLen = 16


function ranNum() {
  for (let i = 0; i < passLen; i++) {
    let randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length) + 1
    randomPass += chars.charAt(randomLetter)
    console.log(randomPass)
  }
  return randomPass
}

function genPass() {
  document.getElementById("div1").textContent = ranNum()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="genPass()">Generate</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the length property on passLen and the variable value is an int.

```
 for ( let i=0; i<passLen; i++){

    let randomLetter = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length) + 1
    randomPass += chars.charAt(randomLetter)
 }
```